# Is it true there's a greater chance of being killed by lightning than of dying on a flight?

Tags: air-travel, safety, statistics

When people try to calm others who are afraid of flying some will claim it's more likely you will be killed by lightning than dying on a flight. Is there any truth in this?

Comment: "...some will claim it's more likely you will be killed by lightning than dying on a flight." You're right, they do, but what a ridiculous approach! One might as well try to convince someone who's claustrophobic that an MRI is quite safe. Of course it's safe, but it's still an awful experience for the claustrophobic patient, and it has nothing to do with safety.

Comment: Who's "you"? Some people don't fly, or fly more or less. Different types of flights different places different airlines etc. Some people live where there is more or less lightning, or spent more or less time out doors etc etc.

Comment: @Dronz - I stopped seeing outdoors as being a difference-maker after lightning went through our son's bedroom. :)

Comment: Your chances of dying on a flight downed by lightning are close (but [not quite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am_Flight_214)) zero.

Comment: mandatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/795/

Comment: It's all about conditional probability, but of course there's a total naive probability as well. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_strike: _"One estimate is that 24,000 people are killed by lightning strikes around the world each year and about 240,000 are injured. Another estimate is that the annual global death toll is 6,000."_ 2014 had 990 commercial airliner fatalities in total, for 33 million flights, i.e. 0.003%. Lightning deaths could be related to people exposed to thunderstorms. Assuming 24k over 1 billion, that's 0.24%; or 2.4% over 100 million exposed. Your choice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Skeptics.SE

Comment: I am voting to keep it open as it is history of this site and it is silly to clear out all that belonged and was deems suitable back then.

Comment: Exactly, it would be better suited for Skeptics.SE, but not that it has a history here, we should leave it open. See also this Meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration?cb=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is: **it depends on where you are, what aircraft you're flying on, how frequently you fly on them, and how often you stand next to tall objects in the middle of a field during thunderstorms (among other factors.)**

If you're talking about the recent average chance of dying in a plane crash on a U.S. mainline air carrier per year vs. the recent average chance of getting killed by lightning in the U.S. per year, then, **yes, you're far more likely to be killed by lightning.** [A couple of dozen people are killed annually by lightning in the U.S.](http://www.lightningsafety.noaa.gov/fatalities.shtml), but there have been *no passenger deaths at all* on any U.S. mainline carrier due to an aviation incident (i.e. not counting "passenger had a heart attack at 30,000 feet") since late 2001 [[source]](http://www.airsafe.com/events/us_ten.htm).

On the other hand, if you're referring to flying daily on a helicopter with a shoddy safety record in a mountainous region where the climate also never results in any [convective available potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_available_potential_energy), then you're much more likely to die in an aviation crash.

---

Real conclusion: Without additional constraints, this is not an especially meaningful thing to compare. If you simply don't fly, your chance of dying as an occupant in an aircraft crash is 0%. If you spend all of your time in a place with no [CAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_available_potential_energy), your chance of dying in a lightning strike is also (almost) 0%.* On the other hand, if you're flying frequently on a private aircraft with shoddy maintenance or you have a habit of standing near tall objects in the middle of large, open fields during thunderstorms, you'd best have good life insurance.

<sub>* There are a few non-thunderstorm possible causes of lightning, [such as volcanic eruptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_thunderstorm), but these probably represent a statistically-insignificant number of lightning deaths.</sub>

Comment: Your answer is a little misleading as you've called out only US Mainline aircraft, which is only a percentage of (commerical) flights in the US. There have been over 100 deaths from regular scheduled airlines in the US since 2002.  Still less than lightning, but more than zero!

Comment: +1 for "how often you stand next to tall objects in the middle of a field during thunderstorms"

Comment: apparently the only reported crash with fatalities is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Reno_Air_Races_crash where the pilot and 10 spectators were killed. So it seems it is more dangerous to look at planes than to fly in one.

Comment: @Doc What time period are you talking about? The page I linked here shows only 139 passenger deaths and 12 crew deaths _total_ on  U.S.-flagged scheduled airlines since late 2001 with the most recent of those over 7 years ago. Its criteria are aircraft that have the capacity to carry at least 10 passengers (regardless of whether 10 pax are actually on board.) Maybe the number you mention includes sightseeing helicopters and Alaskan bush pilots or something? Even then, that seems really high.

Comment: @pnuts Scroll down a bit and you'll see that number is representative of the entire season for the last few years. Also, we're near the end of the season where lightning deaths are most common. The average year over the past 10 only had 4 lightning deaths after August. The vast majority of them have been in June, July, and August.

Comment: @Doc It's also worth pointing out that my whole point was that the answer depends on which flights you're talking about. Obviously, flying on mainline carriers (as the majority of people do) or one of their contracted regional carriers (which together account for the vast majority of all passenger traffic) is much safer than flying around mountains in Alaska in a bush plane or sightseeing helicopter.

Comment: @pnuts With numbers that low, a difference of 4 or 5 in a single year is probably not statistically significant. At any rate, the point of my answer was not so much the numbers for the USA, but rather that the answer to the question will depend entirely on factors that are not specified in the claim. Certainly, the scheduled passenger flights in the USA are a case where the claim is true, but there are many other cases where it wouldn't be. As far as it being a travel question, I don't see how passenger air travel safety isn't travel-related. I suppose it could be moved to Aviation if desired.

Comment: @pnuts Yeah, the NOAA data show them dropping significantly over the last decade. '06 and '07 had about twice as many as recent years. Not sure if this was due to difference in weather patterns or increase in lightning safety practices, though. We're currently in a trough of the periodic tropical weather patterns, for example. Regarding the U.S. airline safety data, the data I cited in the answer is specifically referring to U.S.-flagged carriers, regardless of location, and excluding foreign-flagged carriers in the U.S. (such as the Asiana crash at SFO.)

Comment: @reirab Delta Connection/Comair flight 5191. 2006. 49 dead.   Continental/Colgan Air flight 3407. 2009. 49 dead.   Asiana flight 214. 2013. 3 dead.  All in the US (2 being US airlines). All mainline or their regional carriers, all scheduled passenger flights.  Over 100 deaths in the past 10 years.

Comment: @Doc None of those (except Asiana, which isn't a U.S. airline) is mainline. I originally misread your first comment as over 100 _per year_, though, rather than just over 100 total. Over 100 total is correct when the regionals are included (specifically, 139 as my previous comment mentioned.) Zero is correct for U.S. mainline carriers. Even the regionals haven't had any since 2009, though. Like I said, though, the whole point of the answer was just that exactly what you're talking about needs to be worked out before a reasonable comparison can be made.

Answer (score 14):

According to this [ATAG report](http://aviationbenefits.org/media/26786/ATAG__AviationBenefits2014_FULL_LowRes.pdf) there were 37.4M commercial flights in 2014. There were 20 A1 accidents per [Aviation Safety](https://aviation-safety.net/statistics/period/stats.php?cat=A1). So if you randomly pick a flight, your chances of boarding one which will get into a hull loss accident is one in two million.

According to the [NOAA](http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/general/lib/lig1.pdf) between 1959-1994 on average 90 people were killed by lightning. The 1959 population of the USA was 178M, 1994 population was 260M, taking the mean the chances of killed by lightning is 1:2.43M -- about the same as the flights.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. (but mostly yes)

Considering the USA, because it is easier to find statistics, during 1 year (1999. ok, that's old, but in the newer report I could not find exact numbers).

- *Lightnings* According to @chx's answer, ~90 people are killed by lightning every year.
- *Flights* 691 people died in a plane accident. Source [National Transportation Safety Board page 30](http://www.ntsb.gov/about/Documents/SPC0003.pdf). However, 628 died in private aircrafts. Apparently the remaining 33 died in commercial flights.

So yes, if you consider commercial flights, which is probably the common meaning, but no if you consider all flights.

That could be very different in other countries.

Comment: As @SteveJessop commented to chx's answer, there is no common unit between the statistics. "[W]hy pick one year as the time period for being struck by lightning? Why not choose the average duration of a flight, or the average length of a person's life? The reason the time period is so arbitrary, despite that choice being capable of flipping the answer to the other way around, is that you're comparing quantities with different dimensions (deaths/person/year vs accidents/flight)."

Comment: @Dronz there is a common unit in those statistics: 1 year In the USA. Every year, there are 90 people killed by lightning, and in 1999 there were 33 people killed in commercial flights. I am comparing deaths/year in both cases.

Comment: I changed the formulation to make it a little clearer that I am comparing the same thing. I had the same though as SteveJessop, which is why I added this answer.

Comment: Picking an arbitrary year at random isn't especially meaningful, though, unless that year is actually representative of most years, which, in this case, it isn't. For the mainline U.S. carriers, there hasn't been a single passenger death since 2001.

Comment: @reirab I know. That's the only report I could find with actual numbers of casualties. If you have a trusted source for that number, I'd be happy to change the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @reirab Ignore that last comment, I just saw your answer. It is more complete than mine.